# Read XML to dictionary

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I know this question have been asked multiple times, but I have not manage to solve my problem despite trying several suggestions from other similar questions.

Now I ask instead, in hope to get an answer.

I have this XMl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <WebCommands>
        <WebCommand>
            <FullCommand>@ 05c9fe42-8d89-401d-a9a5-2d82af58e16f This is a test from WebCommands!</FullCommand>
            <TimeStamp>18.06.2015 02:56:22</TimeStamp>
        </WebCommand>
    </WebCommands>
```

I need FullCommand and TimeStamp to be added to my dictionary

```
Dictionary<DateTime, string> commands = new Dictionary<DateTime, string>();
```

How do I:
1. Add the FullCommand and TimeStamp to the dictionary?
2. Convert the TimeStamp string into a proper DateTime?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert XML to Dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952425/how-to-convert-xml-to-dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Add the FullCommand and TimeStamp to the dictionary?

```
var commands = new Dictionary<DateTime, string>();
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("filename.xml");            
foreach (XElement xCommand in xDoc.Root.Elements())
{
    commands.Add(
        DateTime.Parse(xCommand.Element("TimeStamp").Value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),
        xCommand.Element("FullCommand").Value);
}
```

> 2. Convert the TimeStamp string into a proper DateTime

```
DateTime.Parse(xCommand.Element("TimeStamp").Value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

Parsing to `DateTime` is a **culture specific operation**. Make sure you use the correct culture in case `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` isn't viable.